# An error occurs when opening a .mat file in R with readMat: Error in eatRawBuffer(nbfr * size)

Tags: r, matlab

I´m trying to open a .mat file from matlab (version 5.0) in R. I always get an error with this code:

```
readMat("C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\filename.mat")
```

> "Error in eatRawBuffer(nbfr * size) :    INTERNAL ERROR: More bytes
>   was read from the raw buffer than existed: 171534765 > 34275174"

---

I also tried opening it with *read.mat* but then also an error occurs:

> "Error in read.mat(path) : InflateData: inflate returned data error"

---

I think it has something to do with the file because I´m able to open other .mat files with readMat and read.mat. The .mat file has about 9.3 MB.

Comment: Where do these functions come from?

Comment: Is there anything special with the given file, maybe it's too large?

Comment: @TPrie   Is there anyway for you to provide a link to the filename.mat file that you are referencing? If so, then please do so.